# how can I get a JSON like this with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get a JSON like the follows:

```
myJson = {"QC": ["city1","city2"], "NU": ["city3", "city4"], "FO": ["city5","city6"]};
```

I get the data from a database, the structur likes follows:

```
 id      province    city
  1        QC        city1
  2        NU        city3
  3        FO        city5
  4        NU        city4
  5        QC        city2
  6        FO        city6
```

Tanks very much for the tipps

Comment: You get the data from the database as a multiline string of records? What server side language are you using to interface with the database? What data structure is being used to store the output? There is too much missing information to reasonably answer the question.

Comment: Check stack **cookbook** ;)

Comment: You create that data structure on the server side with whatever language you are using and then convert it to JSON. This is really all we can see given that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the rows. Keep the `province` as key. Before adding do a check if the key is already present. If already present add to array.Something like this,

```
if(obj[key]){
  obj[key].push(city);
}else{
  obj[key] = [];
  obj[key].push(city);
}
```

Comment: So you are assuming that the OP uses Node.js? Because I doubt that they can access the DB from the browser. I just think there is not enough information to properly answer this question.

Comment: Just giving the pseudo code. I have no idea what language he has on server side.

Comment: Hi Subir Kumar Sao, it works, Thank you very much